# What are those "deck of cards" objects that various sutras are printed on?

Tags: sutras

I used to go to a Tibetan Buddhist community where they were constantly reading Buddhist scriptures off of little stacks of cards. They were wide aspect ratio, and had the syllables of various mantras written out phonetically on them.

Is there a word for this object? I always wanted to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

In Singhalese they are called Puskola. I think they are known as 'Ola Leafs' or Palm-leaf manuscripts in common English. They are made out of palm leafs.

Comment: The process of making them are detailed here in the you tube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAIkMkmLFPQ